# Stop UIButton turning blue when pressed

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibutton

In my iPad app I have a UIButton that when pressed initiates some data transfer which takes time. During this time the button turns blue as shown:

[image]

Is there anyway of changing this colour?

Comment: do you execute this data transfer on the main thread? You should consider doing hard work on some background thread to not block the UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the tint color, it will be used when button is highlighted.

```
[myButton setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 50)];
    [button setTitle:@"hi" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```